# "Entrypoint not found" error

Tags: dll, c++

I recently installed the GCC & G++ compilers using Mingw. I've written a small test-program and it seems to work just fine until i use the "delete" keyword. An error window pops up titled "program.exe - Entrypoint not found"
The pop-up is written in dutch but in english this is basically what it sais:

"Can't find entrypoint of procedure_ZdlPvj in DLL-file C:\Users\tlins\Desktop\program.exe"

I am no expert in C++ compilers so forgive me if im missing something obvious.

Here is the code i used to test:

```
class Node
{
public:
    float value;
};

int main()
{   
    Node* node = new Node();

    delete node;    
}
```

Nothing wrong with it right?

Edit: it **does** work when using *malloc()* & *free()* for some reason.

Comment: Are using C++ 98, C++ 11, or C++ 14 to compile the code?  `delete` takes a pointer.  You are currently not passing a pointer.  You are most likely trying to call a C++ function that does not exist.

Comment: @Ramhound I am using C++ 11, but i don't understand what you mean with the rest of that comment. 'node' looks like a normal pointer to me and 'delete' does exist.

Comment: I apologize, I miss read the code, is absolutely is a pointer.  At this point this question actually belongs on Stack Overflow not Super User.

Comment: How do you compile your program?

Comment: @n.m. i use G++ compiler so i just type 'g++ program.cpp -o program' in the console. It compiles fine btw, i get the error popup only when i run it.

Comment: There's no problem with your program, there's a problem with your compiler installation. I cannot tell what the problem is, but try removing and reinstalling it.